# Load assets from Flutter into native code

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

Im trying to load an asset from flutter project "asset" folder into native code. For example I want this file `/assets/labels.txt` (Flutter folder) to load it in a Kotlin script in the path `android/app/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt`.

I successfully connect Flutter into Kotlin but I have errors when I try to load it.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "your_channel_name"
    private val LABELS_PATH = "assets/labels.txt"  // 

    private fun loadLabels() {
        try {
            Log.d("LoadLabels", "Loading labels...")

            val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(assets.open(LABELS_PATH)))
            labels = reader.readLines()
            reader.close()
            labels.forEach { line ->
                Log.d("TextFileContent", line)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

// ...
}
```

These are my errors :

> D/LoadLabels(11123): Loading labels...
> W/System.err(11123): java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/labels.txt

So my question is this :

**I must load the assets always from Flutter project folder or from the same folder that the native code script is? Also what is my error here?**

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70809816/how-exactly-to-access-flutter-assets-from-within-android-java-plugin-platfor/70817917#70817917

Comment: @RichardHeap that's for plugin. i want to know how to do that in activity.

Comment: Im a little bit confused also about activity and plugins , i just want to run a specific function for tensorflow(some audio classifications). Do i have to do this as a plugin? Also why i have to keep the binding?First time saw that im confused,every time i hit a function on native code i must to a binding too? Thanks again.