Load Flutter assets in iOS
I am trying to load an asset in my iOS Swift Code inside a WidgetExtension. I found this documentation but the code seems to be deprecated.
With this the project builds:
let assetPath = "assets/icons.png"
let key = FlutterDartProject.lookupKey(forAsset: assetPath)
UIImage(named: key, in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil)!

But the widget doesn't really render the changes. I also couldn't debug the widget since it needs the Flutter dependency to start debugging from Xcode it seems. So how can I access the assets from the iOS Swift WidgetExtension and how can I debug it with when importing Flutter in the Swift code.

Did you see the (rather out of date) ios code here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70809816/how-exactly-to-access-flutter-assets-from-within-android-java-plugin-platfor/70817917#70817917

Yes but did not work either

Are you adding the asset to an asset catalog you have added to your widget extension target in Xcode?

You can enable widget debugging by having same app group identifier in main app and widget target, than setting breakpoint in widget extension code.
Make sure your asset is added to both the target.

Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question. I want to use the assets from Flutter only.
